# Google Maps - Limit marker placement to visible map tiles

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a map where I need to place markers for locations drawn from a database. The locations can be from one end of the country to the other and I want to limit marker placement to only the visible map area.

What segments of the api cover this? Are there any best practices for handling this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the bounds of the map with:

```
bounds = map.getBounds();
```

The result is a LatLngBounds object. Then for a marker `marker`, you can test if it is in the map with:

```
if ( bounds.contains(marker.getPosition()) ) {
}
```